# Required to Convert Rows Values in Columns, based on ID

Tags: excel

I need to Convert Rows Values in Columns, based on ID.
I have bunch of Input Data and required Output Data as shown in the example below:

[image]

Waiting for your solution on priority.
You can provide your solution on in xls of ms-access

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the Help Center on asking questions. This is NOT a free code-writing service or tutorial site. You need to demonstrate you've made an effort to solve the problem and show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transpose function on the cells you want to change